# Blockscout Explorer : Issue with Smart contract Verification Service

Tags: besu, blockscout

We have successfully set up a Blockscout explorer using the docker-compose containers from the repository (https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout/tree/master/docker-compose). The explorer is currently running and synchronizing with the blockchain network without any issues.

Additionally, we have hosted the Rust services for smart contract verification, and they are functioning as expected.

However, we encountered an error when attempting to verify and publish the smart contract in the contract code.

Could you please provide assistance or guidance to resolve this issue?

[image: Please refer the screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a new variable, `SECRET_KEY_BASE=$key`, add in envs/common-blockscout.env file，You can generate a new key with this command mix phx.gen.secret ,You can find related information in this article https://docs.blockscout.com/for-developers/manual-deployment